# How to generate select elements via JS/JQuery in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

page.js

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // Look for changes to input
  $("#input").change(function() {
    // Assign input to var
    var inputsequence = $(this).val()
    // Split Input Sequence into array
    var sequencearray = inputsequence.split("")
    // Loop over Sequence Array to create select elements
    for (var i = 0, len = sequencearray.length; i < len; i++) {
      // Append Select elements to oligosoutput element id
      $("#output").append(GenerateSelect(sequencearray[i]))
    }
  });

function GenerateSelect(base) {
  var options = ""
  switch(base.toUpperCase()) {
  case 'A':
    options = "<%= options_from_collection_for_select(SelectOptions.where(\"category = 'A'\"), :id, :option %>"
  case 'B':
    options = "<%= options_from_collection_for_select(SelectOptions.where(\"category = 'B'\"), :id, :option %>"
  default:
    //default
}
return options
```

}
    })

page.html.erb

```
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<div>
  <span id="output"></span>
</div>
```

When the user inputs a string into the #input textarea I want to capture the value and split it into an array. For each item in that array, I want a select box created for each index.

I want to populate the select boxes with data from the SelectOptions model. The data from the select boxes won't be posted to a form, it will be processed via more javascript to compile a string which will be submitted via form.

For example, if the user inputs ABC, it would create a select box for A with the data from SelectOptions.where("category = 'a') which would contain: Apple, Antelope, Ape, etc.

What is the best way of accomplishing the task of populating the select elements and rendering them on the page during the $("#input").change() event?

Comment: I'd rather prefer keyup function instead of chage on inputs.

Comment: another question.. suppose that a user entered "asd" to the input. You want to create a select tag with an options of value with "asd" or did ı understand wrong?

Comment: For now I'm just trying to get the functionality, for now the change() method works for testing. If they put in asd, there would be three select tags/drop downs, one for A, one for S, and one for D, all with potentially different select options.

Edit: 
The select options for A would pull from:
 SelectOptions.where("category = 'a')

S would pull from:

SelectOptions.where("category = 's') etc..

Comment: But what you gonna include as options A is it dynamic as well? Where will they come from?

Comment: all you need to do is for example for "asd" create 3 select tags and get "a" "s" "d" as individual vars to referance select.options. If i create you the code for select tags and get the letters individually will you be able to call options inside the relative select tags?

Comment: Editing main post with what I have so far, it outputs ERB, which doesn't work, but this is essentially the functionality i'm looking for. Edited the GenerateSelect function in page.js

Comment: Also, options var would need to be wrapped in a select tag before being returned, but doing it that way just outputs the erb as text onto the page